# Cardboard photosphere(built in Unity3d) doesn't run in iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, photosphere

Long story short, photosphere was able to run in Android and inside Unity3d. But it doesn't work for my i phone. I have come a long way with solving errors and change many settings in Xcode after reading many online posts, but still can't run it in i phone. I think its better if I list major changes that I made along the way:
Please help!! Have stuck on it for days!!

1. For arm64: I have IL2CPP as Scripting Backend in Unity3d, architecture is then default to x86_64
2. For Xcode settings: I follow this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIkJAKcz8DE
3. For  -undefined and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) :

I have set Enable bitcode to NO. 
Set Build Active Architecture Only to NO. 
Set Architectures as Standard(arm64). 
Set valid Architecture as arm64
Tried clean and build couple times.

4. Now have: 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E307A.png)